# Diesel fuel pressure issue Fiat Punto 1.3 JTD

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, pressure, fiat

I have a Fiat Punto 188 1.3 JTD Multijet and an issue, that brings me a headache since 2 years. The car is from 2005 and already has 180 000 miles down. Almost every time, the I fast accelerate from lower rotation in range from 800 - 2800 RPM, my car get a strong shock. Motor-Check lights up and since then you can not get higher rotation then 3000 RPM until you start the car new. 
After this I get two Error Messages: 1. Fuel pressure to low. 2. Fuel pressure to high. I already changes all the fuel pressure sensors and checked the high pressure pump at the car workshop. They have no idea what else could be wrong. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: This sounds like the car is going into a "limp home" mode.  Could you post the exact error messages that you are getting?  I assume those are coming from some sort of OBD-II scanner or equivalent.  FYI: my car can go into a limp home mode if the fuel filler cap isn't on tightly enough - that might be an easy thing to check.

Comment: Also, do you actually mean **RPM** (rotations per minute) instead of **RMP** (??) in body of your text? Just making sure.

Comment: @BobCross, already checked. I also changed the fuel filter and the appropriate seal. Same issue. I will read the error once again this weekend, because I didn't note them.

Comment: @Paulster2, Yes, I corrected that. Thx. It should be rotations per minute.

Comment: Look up fiatecuscan.net on the net. It is very good free Fiat software download. The software is a step by step quide for Fiats and their particular quirks.

Comment: @AllanOsborne you mean multiecuscan.net? Ok. I will test it this weekend.

Comment: OOOps. They have changed the name. But it will track the engine through its revolutions per minute and give you pointers.

Comment: @Watsche Were you ever able to find the cause of this problem?